# JS keep reporting "toString" method is undefined

Tags: javascript, tostring

My goal is to alphabetize the givin string. For example, given string "The Holy Bible", should get "BbeehHilloTy". Below is the code:

```
function alphabetized(s) {
  let sArray = s.split(" ").join("").split("");
  //below to perform a bubble sorting
  for (let i = 0; i < sArray.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < sArray.length - i; j++) {
      if ((sArray[j].toString().toLowerCase()) > (sArray[j + 1].toString().toLowerCase())) {
        let tempItem = sArray[j];
        sArray[j] = sArray[j + 1];
        sArray[j + 1] = tempItem;
      }
    }
  }
  return sArray.join("");
}

console.log(alphabetized('The Holy Bible'));
```

I kept getting the error from JS console:

```
if ((sArray[j].toString().toLowerCase()) > (sArray[j + 1].toString().toLowerCase())) {
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Read the message closely. It's not "toString is undefined", it is "toString **of** undefined".

Comment: When `i` is `0`, then `sArray.length - i` will be the same as `sArray.length`, so `sArray[j + 1]` will be out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the problem.
the variable is not defined, toString method cannot be called.
so you just have to add this code. if you don't want do anything

```
if(!sArray[j + 1]) continue;
```

this is a small tip. debuging is a good tool to code. try it!

Comment: Thank you! Before calling toString() method, I should have evaluated the existence of the value who will call that method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that `toString` is undefined. It is that you are trying to call `toString()` on something that *is* undefined.

Since you're calling `toString()` on the results of evaluating an array, it seems likely that the element of the array you're referencing isn't valid. You do this in two places: `sArray[j]` and `sArray[j+1 ]`. Since you're looping over j from 0 to the length of the array, you may evaluate one past the length of the array.

As part of debugging, try logging both the value of `j` and what you think the character you're evaluating should be.

Comment: Very clear comment, looks like this is brand new to me... Thank you!